# vaadin 8 combobox not execute addSelectionListener

Tags: combobox, vaadin8

I have problem with my combobox. When I select an item from my combobox it does not go to my addSelectionListener except for the first time when the program starts. How to make it take the user's selection.

here is the code:

```
private Tirage tirage;
private ComboBox<Tirage> comboBoxTir2;
List<Tirage> tirages;

    tirages = tirageService.findByTirageFutur(produit.getId(), envService.getDateLogique());
    comboBoxTir2 = new ComboBox<>();
    comboBoxTir2.setItems(tirages);
    comboBoxTir2.setItemCaptionGenerator(Tirage::getNoTirage);

    comboBoxTir2.addSelectionListener(event -> {
        tirage = event.getValue();
    });
    sectionVerticalPage.addComponent(comboBoxTir2);
```

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: How do you figure out the listener is called only once?

Comment: I went  into debug mode

Comment: That should defenitlly work. Can you make a SSCCE, so we can reproduce the issue?

Comment: My list of tirages comes from a query from a table.

Comment: I have 3 combobox in my application.

Comment: First  combox box of product wich is list of product from a table. When the user select a product the comboxBox of tirages gets all the tirages for that product. The setItems for the tirage comboBox changes depending of the product. The Product comboBox  works fine and go to the addSelectionListerner code. But the tirage comboBox  goes the first time and never go the addSelectionListener after. The List of Tirages comes from a JPA Query. Could it be the cause of my problem?